# 'router-outlet' is not a known element ANGULAR

Tags: angular, angular-directive, router-outlet

I want to configure my route `/` contact, but when I show the contents of this view with the `<router-outlet> </router-outlet>` tag, my console displays the following error:

[image: Console]

The first thing I did was add this line in my app.module.ts:

```
import {RouterModule , Routes} from '@angular/router';
import { ContactoComponent } from './contacto/contacto.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'contacto', component: ContactoComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    CabezeraComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    ContactoComponent,
    BodyComponent, 
  ],
  exports: [
     RouterModule 
    ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],  
})
```

then in my base route I make the call to a header, a footer and my route with the tag `<router-outlet>`, the problem is that when I run, my browser goes to target and throws me the error mentioned above in the console. ... this is an error of the version?
I am calling the localhost / contact path well, I am currently working with angle 6 .... any help for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove **`RouterModule`**  under exports

```
 exports: [
     RouterModule //remove this
 ],
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

@NgModule({
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes)               
],
declarations: [
    AppComponent,  
    CabezeraComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    ContactoComponent,
    BodyComponent,      
],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {

}
```

There is no need to configurate the exports in `AppModule`, because `AppModule` wont be imported by other modules in your application.